# Creating this semicircle arcs design using Opengl. Creating different arcs by changing theta

Tags: opengl

I am trying to draw this design using OpenGl . I can draw the semicircle arcs with theta from 0 to 3.14. I need to know how can I draw the semicircles on different axis. I tried to experiment with the theta but I couldn't get the desired result. I also needed some help in understanding how I can construct arcs of different lengths.

[image]

```
void circle(float xc,float yc,float a, float b,float c,float r,float u,float v)
{
  a=rand()%10;
  b=rand()%10;
  c=rand()%10;
  a=(a/100);b=(b/100);c=(c/100);

  int three;
    three=rand()%3;
  if(three==0)
    {
      a=1;
    }
  else if(three==1)
    {
      b=1;
    }
  else
    c=1;

  glColor3f(a,b,c);

  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  float x,y;
  float theta=0,dtheta;
  dtheta=(1/r);
  for(theta=u;theta<(v);theta=theta+dtheta)
    {
      x=xc+r*cos(theta);
      y=yc+r*sin(theta);
      glVertex2i(x,y);
        glFlush();

    }

  glEnd();
  glFlush();

}

void mydisplay()
{
  float a,b,c;
  srand(time(NULL));
  a=rand()%20;
  b=rand()%20;
  c=rand()%20;
  a=a/100;b=b/100;c=c/100;
  glClearColor(a,b,c,0.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  float xc=205.00,x,yc=205.00,y;
  float theta=0,dtheta,r=2;
  dtheta=(3.14/50);

  int three;
  a=rand()%10;
  b=rand()%10;
  c=rand()%10;
  a=(a/100);b=(b/100);c=(c/100);
  three=rand()%3;
  if(three==0)
    {
      a=1;
    }
  else if(three==1)
    {
      b=1;
    }
  else
    c=1;
  for(r=1;r<=100;r=r+5)
    {
      x=xc+r*cos(theta);
      y=yc+r*sin(theta);
      circle(x,y,a,b,c,r,0,3.14);
        glFlush();
    }
  glEnd();

  glFlush();
      sleep(1);
  glutPostRedisplay();

}
```

Comment: I was just trying to check how I could draw a vertical semicircle first and then I was going to alter the code to create the design.To create it vertically I did this circle(x,y,a,b,c,r,3.14/2,(3.14/2)+3.14); but I am getting a different result.

Comment: I just did get something similar to what I wanted. What I did wrong here is that I used a code which I used to generate another design which I created. I now understood that I was passing the x and y as centers of the circle funtion defined above and that is how I am getting the errors. It is funny how everytime when I post on SO I suddenly start to get answers on my own. I am able to get the vertical ones by changing it like this  x=xc+r*cos(theta);    
  for(r=1;r<=100;r=r+5)
    {
      
      y=yc+r*sin(theta);
      circle(x,y,a,b,c,r,-3.14/2,-(3.14/2)+3.14);
        glFlush();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void circle(float a, float b,float c,float r,float u,float v,float chy,float chx)
{
  a=rand()%10;
  b=rand()%10;
  c=rand()%10;
  a=(a/100);b=(b/100);c=(c/100);

  int three;
    three=rand()%3;
  if(three==0)
    {
      a=1;
    }
  else if(three==1)
    {
      b=1;
    }
  else
    c=1;

  glColor3f(a,b,c);

  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  float x,y,xc=205+chx,yc=205 + chy;
  float theta=0,dtheta;
  dtheta=(1/r);
  for(theta=u;theta<(v);theta=theta+dtheta)
    {
      x=xc+r*cos(theta);
      y=yc+r*sin(theta);
      glVertex2i(x,y);
        glFlush();

    }

  glEnd();
  glFlush();

}

void mydisplay()
{
  float a,b,c;
  srand(time(NULL));
  a=rand()%20;
  b=rand()%20;
  c=rand()%20;
  a=a/100;b=b/100;c=c/100;
  glClearColor(a,b,c,0.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  float xc=205.00,x,yc=205.00,y;
  float theta=0,dtheta,r=2;
  dtheta=(3.14/50);

  int three;
  a=rand()%10;
  b=rand()%10;
  c=rand()%10;
  a=(a/100);b=(b/100);c=(c/100);
  three=rand()%3;
  if(three==0)
    {
      a=1;
    }
  else if(three==1)
    {
      b=1;
    }
  else
    c=1;

  for(r=1;r<=100;r=r+5)
    {
      x=xc+r*cos(theta);
      y=yc+r*sin(theta);
      circle(a,b,c,r,0,3.14,0,r);
        glFlush();
    }
    for(r=1;r<=100;r=r+5)
    {
      x=xc+r*cos(theta);
      y=yc+r*sin(theta);
      circle(a,b,c,r,-3.14/2,-(3.14/2)+3.14,-r,0);
        glFlush();
    }
    for(r=1;r<=100;r=r+5)
    {
      x=xc+r*cos(theta);
      y=yc+r*sin(theta);
      circle(a,b,c,r,3.14/2,(2*3.14)-(3.14/2),r,0);
        glFlush();
    }
    for(r=1;r<=100;r=r+5)
    {
      x=xc+r*cos(theta);
      y=yc+r*sin(theta);
      circle(a,b,c,r,3.14,(2*3.14),0,-r);   
        glFlush();
    }
  glEnd();

  glFlush();
  sleep(1);
  glutPostRedisplay();

}
```

Comment: This is what I did to get the design but I would like to understand more on how to draw arcs what I did was just experimenting on the values when I knew that 2*3.14 would complete the circle.

Comment: So I am still waiting for the other half part of the question to be answered.